# extract associated values from text documents with tables as returns

Tags: text-mining

I've got a challenge to extract information from pdf documents. I've managed to translate associated information from the pdf into data frames in r. The challenge is for information buried in text, would it possible to get the information returning as tables?

For example, I have a list of animals, monkey, puffin, tuna, etc as observations and their features as variables, e.g. head, tail, eyes, hair, length, weight...I ask the code to use these queries to search in relevant documents returning with a table in the format of rows as observations and columns as variables (if no values were found, return as NAs in associated cells)?

I have used R to extract parameters of interest from pdf files. My code is not flexible and only enables me to extract and tidy certain pages of interest. These pages are fairly structured appendix with tags I can use to narrow down my search.

Comment: Are you mining text to make the data set formatted as csv? Could you also add the code sample what you are using?

Comment: Yes, the code can export as csv. The approach is using the library 'pdftools'  to extract key pages from appendix using regex. Example document can be found via the [link](https://d28rz98at9flks.cloudfront.net/37052/37052.pdf).

Comment: The simple idea is to read the PDF into R first as list of lists (each list inside the list is a page of the document) then split the text into different columns by any words followed by ':' or '//s*:' (as regex ).

Comment: You get the idea?  This is not flexible and one has to tailor the code for documents of different structures. My question really is about possibilities to take a different approach by some kind of flexible search methods or tools which enable one to transform parameters of interest from a pdf (or word or any other text documents) to tables.